# How should I install Bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, frameworks

I learned two ways: Putting some links directly into your html file and installing a Bootstrap app using a terminal. What’s the difference between these two ways and witch is better?

Comment: This question does not meet stack overflow guidelines to 'How to ask a question'. That being said there is also a third way... downloading the Bootstrap files and placing them in your project files. I would reccommend using the direct links as that way you are always guaranteed to have and updates that may happen

Comment: I just read through the guidelines and I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linking to a Bootstrap CDN has the following advantages:

1. You do not have to serve the Bootstrap files from your web server
2. Because many sites use the same CDN, it is possible that your users have already downloaded and cached the Bootstrap files when visiting another site that uses that CDN.  This will then improve the speed of the first load of your site.
3. Potentially, there is yet more improved speed, because some CDNs distribute content from hosting servers geographically closer to your user.

The disadvantage is that if the CDN server(s) goes down, so does your site.

Serving your own copy of the Bootstrap files has the following advantages:

1. You aren't relying on a third party to serve your site.

The disadvantage is that the initial visit to your site will be slower because your users will have to download the copy of Bootstrap unique to your site.

There is no "better" method - it is a matter of weighing the pros and cons and deciding which option is appropriate for your site.